# ZMQ throughput optimization

Tags: c++11, zeromq, throughput

I developed an application that has very various zmq-message sizes. In average those are ~177 byte, but in reality most messages are very small < 20b and just few messages have very big size > 3000b.

Now the network is the limiting factor (1gbit ethernet). I can reach ~50MByte/s. Another benchmark told me that the network throughput can reach ~85 MByte/s with a paket size of >256byte.

I think my results are that low due to the fact that most pakets have very small size. Am I right? Is there a possiblity to optimize zmq for using the whole bandwidth for my application, too? Extended batching for example?

Regards

Comment: not sure what you're asking, can you be more clear?

Comment: I got an application that generates zmq-messages with very various sizes. Most of those messages are quiet small and some few are quiet big. As a consequence of these "paket characteristic" I can just get a network throughput of ~50 MByte/s in a 1 Gbit ethernet.

Running the zmq-performance test gave me a similar result than this one: http://zeromq.org/results:10gbe-tests. It says that the network bandwidth can be used completely when pakets are greater than ~100b. Why isn't it possible to exhaust the full bandwidth with smaller pakets and are there some optimizations possible?

Comment: Hmm, not knowing the full details of your network, that's a tough nut to crack. I did, however, offer an answer below regarding high speed subscribers when throughput becomes an issue; hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The ZeroMQ guide illustrates the [Black Box Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#High-Speed-Subscribers-Black-Box-Pattern) for high speed subscribers. In essence, it uses a two stream approach (per node), where each stream has it own I/O thread and subscriber, both of whom are bound to a specific network interface (NIC) and core, so you'll need two network adapters and multi-cores per node for this to work. You can read the full details in the [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#High-Speed-Subscribers-Black-Box-Pattern).

Comment: For me this is not useful as I need bidirectional communication. Any other idea?

Comment: You can use this approach for processing incoming messages, but send responses on a separate, async channel.

Comment: Ah okay, I will check whether I can use that approach.